# Table missing in SQL Server 2012 created using aspnet_regsql

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to implement security policies in my website using asp.net membership providers. I run `aspnet_regsql` from following path `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`. Then I selected my database, and I got all the tables I want. It works fine, in my local server.

Now I want to implement the same on my server. I just logged into server using rdp and execute the same procedure. On the server, I can see only 11 tables, in which the following tables are not showing

1. __MigrationHistory
2. AspNetRoles
3. AspNetUserClaims
4. AspNetUserLogins
5. AspNetUserRoles
6. AspNetUsers

Are these tables hidden? On local server create user,login functionality works fine. But on the server, no luck. I am using SQL Server 2012 I logged in as administrator in server. Any help?

Comment: Are you sure you did not exeute the script in your master DB or another database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't suppose you noticed any errors when you ran the procedure the firs time?
What is the error you're getting on the server?

You can try running the procedure again, or even just script the missing tables and create them on the server.

Comment: you said on your local server create user, login functionality works, but on the server no luck... does that not mean you're getting an error?

Comment: when i run in server i got this error message "An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."

Comment: Did you try scripting the missing tables and creating them on the server

Comment: is there any odrer in executing scripts,i can create only __MigrationHistory table all others get foriegn key constraints errors

Comment: Yes there would be an order, but I don't know what that is. I'm guessing AspNetUsers and AspNetRoles should probably be one of the first ones you create. Just keep running the create table script until all the errors you're getting is 'object already exists'. After creating the missing tables, you might also want to copy the data inside the tables over to the server

Comment: i scripted all the tables. and run my website. but i got new erorr as {"The provider did not return a ProviderManifestToken string."}. my connection string is  <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=208.81.176.25;Initial Catalog=SposUsers;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Comment: you're going to have to give us a little more than that... Did you transfer the data?

Comment: what data do you need?

Comment: the data from YOUR local server for all the missing tables that you created. There will probably be some roles, etc that gets created by default, that won't be there because the create table failed.

Comment: only __MigrationHistory tbale in local contains some values

Comment: k . this is the erorr i got after scripted missing tables into server "An error occurred while getting provider information from the database. This can be caused by Entity Framework using an incorrect connection string. Check the inner exceptions for details and ensure that the connection string is correct."

Comment: This new error is not related to missing tables anymore. Try searching on this new error to point you in a direction.